# Running two Pentaho instances on one machine

Tags: linux, postgresql, tomcat, pentaho

I want to upgrade our Pentaho-server CE installation, from version 7.1 to version 9.0 (because version 7.1 has serious issue with datetime picker and timezones).

However, I cannot turn off our current 7.1 instance, spend few days/weeks to make 9.0 work and than turn that one on. I have to do 9.0 while 7.1 is still running.

To avoid duplicate work, I was thinking about installing 9.0 to alongside currently running 7.1, on the same server, where the database and other stuff is.

I am thinking about 2 options how to make it:

1. Test it during night, at about 22:00 stop 7.1 instance and start 9.0 instance to do all the tests and work, when finished, stop 9.0 and start 7.1 again.
2. Have both instances running simultaneously, on different ports.

I have already checked up about this topic, since I am not very familiar with tomcat. Most of sources only mention ports changing, which is obvious even for me. But I am little bit worried about the internal databases (`jackrabbit`, `quartz` and `hibernate`). Our currently running instance 7.1 is using PostgreSQL for them, and I want to have it that way for 9.0 too. However what I worry about is, that if I run Pentaho9.0 over those internal databases, it will break the older instance 7.1 and make it unusable.

So, my question is, will running pentaho 9.0 over pentaho 7.1 internal databases (`jackrabbit`, `quartz` and `hibernate`) make those incompatible with the 7.1 version? And how to safely run 2 pentaho instances on one machine (while having in mind that the switch from 7.1 to 9.0 in future shouldn't be too complicated :)

Comment: what I usually do in those more complex upgrade scenarios is deploy a copy of the production system into a virtual lab, test the upgrade there, document all the changes and then upgrade the production system with those preparations to speed things up. Having everything in a virtualized environment makes this much much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found very simple solution. In Pentaho documentation, there is a script from importing/exporting all the stuff from one Pentaho installation to another. (users, reports, connections, etc).

So, I do not need to run 2 instances and do lots of work on Pentaho 9 to move all the stuff from currently running Pentaho 7.1 instance.

All I do is export everything from Pentaho 7.1. Turn it off, start Pentaho 9 and import all the stuff there. Simple.

Source:
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0P0/Managing_the_Pentaho_Repository/Backup_and_Restore_Pentaho_Repositories

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.0/Setup/Backup_and_restore_Pentaho_repositories

Answer (score 0):

I have recently completed Pentaho 7.1 to Pentaho 8.3 upgrade activity.

My advise

1. Do not run two servers on the same machine simultaneously, it creates lot of memory issue even if you have high machine configuration
2. Take backup of your repository (jackrabbit, quartz and hibernate), once your start the 9.1 server pentaho will internally make your repository to 9.1 compatible hence it will be not useful when you want to switch back to 7.1
3. create a copy of your database(jackrabbit, quartz and hibernate), with 9.1 use this copy and keep using 7.1 at it is.

Note : Pentaho 9.1 is not a stable version, check all your use-cases and open jira bugs related to version 9.1 before you consider upgrading or updating your pentaho version.